# Copy builded folder to another directory

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

I have a /dist (builded folder project) and i want to webpack copy this folder to an another directory (../../static).
Is it possible to webpack copy my build folder to another directory when finish the building process? The folders are not in the same hierarchy

Here's a print to show better the idea:
[Folder Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lm5Ib.png)

Comment: What do you mean by 'webpack copy'? Just copy?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a configuration that I think will do what you want (ref [this issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1189)).

```
{
    entry: {
        '/dist/bundle': 'entry.js',
        '/../../static/bundle': 'entry.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem! Using https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-shell-plugin

After webpack build i ran a command to shell to copy my folder to the destination.